# R - substring phrase in middle of string

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, substring, substr

I want to substring out a phrase that's in the middle of a string in R. The string is a field in a data frame. It data frame looks something like this:

```
Common.name price description
Animal 1    $50   Field Collected\nRoughly 2-3 Inches In Length\nVibrant Red Coloration\nWill Do Fine In Groups\nFeeding On Various Vegetation & Fruits\nSizes Range From 1-2.5 Feet In Total Length\nField Collected\nSizes Vary From Juvenile ...
Animal 2    $40   Captive Bred\nApproximately 10-12 Inches In Length\nBeautiful Hybrid to Add To Your Collection\nInsane Patterning And Beautiful Vibrant Colors\nMales And Females...
...    ...  ...   ...
Animal 500  $29   Field Collected Beauties\nMales And Females Available\nApproximate Length: no bigger than a penny\nAmazingly Friendly! Make Great Pets!\nOnly Reach About 9 Inches At Most!\nFeeding On Vitamin Dusted Greens And ...
```

I want to extract the length and units in each description as new fields. For Animal 1 it would be 2-3 in one field and inches in another field. For Animal 500 the length would be "no bigger than a penny" and the unit field would be NA.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: You have got to understand that extracting "no smaller than a sloth's eyelash and no bigger than an adolescent pygmy marmoset's tail" is gonna be almost impossible, right?

Comment: haha, yes I was hoping someone had a trick up their sleeve. But most of them are actual numbers so if worst come to worse I'll manually add the ones without numbers

Comment: This would be easier if each description had in it `Length: 5`. But instead it uses `Approximately` and `Roughly`. You'd have to write cases for all of these. If it was general enough, you could use `regexpr` to get the character number where the identifier happened maybe.

Comment: `res <- grep("(?<=Approximately).*",  "Approximately 10-12 Inches In Length", perl = T, value = T)` does any one know why this would not work to extract text after "Approximately"?

Comment: Haha that is funny @cory. I think you will need to first split the description field by "\n" then look for the set that has some keywords like length, inches etc. Once you have that info then do a separate extraction of measurement and units. This will be a custom code. Don't know of any other generic solve for this.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This Regex will do the following:

- Match line starting with `Animal` followed by a number
- capture the Animal number
- find the first field with the word `length` somewhere in the field
- if the length is expressed as numbers

  - capture the length as a single number `234` or a range of numbers `3-342`
  - assume the string after the numbers is the unit of measure
- if the length is expressed as some weird text

  - capture everything after the `:`
  - leave the UnitOfMeasure as null

**The Regex**

`^(?<Animal>Animal\s[0-9]+)\s+\S+\s+(?:(?:(?!\\n|$).)*\\n)*?(?=(?:(?!\\n).)*Length)(?:(?:(?!\\n).)*?(?<Length>[0-9]+\s*(?:-\s*[0-9]+)?)\s+(?<UnitOfMeasure>\S+)|(?:(?!\\n).)*?Length:\s*(?<Length>(?:(?!\\n).)*))?`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Notes**

- I used the following flags: multiline, global, and allow duplicate subpattern names
- I wasn't sure if the `\n` strings in your source text were literally `\n` or if they represented return characters. So this regex is constructed to assume they are literally a `\` character followed by a `n` character. If you meant these characters to represent a new line character, then change all the `\\n` to `\n` in the regex

## Examples

**Live example**

https://regex101.com/r/nL1fW1/2

**Sample input text**

```
Common.name price description
Animal 1    $50   Field Collected\nRoughly 2-3 Inches In Length\nVibrant Red Coloration\nWill Do Fine In Groups\nFeeding On Various Vegetation & Fruits\nSizes Range From 1-2.5 Feet In Total Length\nField Collected\nSizes Vary From Juvenile ...
Animal 2    $40   Captive Bred\nApproximately 10-12 Inches In Length\nBeautiful Hybrid to Add To Your Collection\nInsane Patterning And Beautiful Vibrant Colors\nMales And Females...
Animal 3    $40   Captive Bred\nApproximately 10 Inches In Length\nBeautiful Hybrid to Add To Your Collection\nInsane Patterning And Beautiful Vibrant Colors\nMales And Females...
...    ...  ...   ...
Animal 500  $29   Field Collected Beauties\nMales And Females Available\nApproximate Length: no bigger than a penny\nAmazingly Friendly! Make Great Pets!\nOnly Reach About 9 Inches At Most!\nFeeding On Vitamin Dusted Greens And ...
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = Animal 1    $50   Field Collected\nRoughly 2-3 Inches
[0][Animal] = Animal 1
[0][Length] = 2-3
[0][UnitOfMeasure] = Inches

[1][0] = Animal 2    $40   Captive Bred\nApproximately 10-12 Inches
[1][Animal] = Animal 2
[1][Length] = 10-12
[1][UnitOfMeasure] = Inches

[2][0] = Animal 3    $40   Captive Bred\nApproximately 10 Inches
[2][Animal] = Animal 3
[2][Length] = 10
[2][UnitOfMeasure] = Inches

[3][0] = Animal 500  $29   Field Collected Beauties\nMales And Females Available\nApproximate Length: no bigger than a penny
[3][Animal] = Animal 500
[3][UnitOfMeasure] = 
[3][Length] = no bigger than a penny
```

## Explanation

This was copied from the explanation field in the live link above.

```
^ assert position at start of a line
(?<Animal>Animal\s[0-9]+) Named capturing group Animal
Animal matches the characters Animal literally (case sensitive)
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\S+ match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?:(?:(?!\\n|$).)*\\n)*? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
(?:(?!\\n|$).)* Non-capturing group
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?!\\n|$) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
1st Alternative: \\n
\\ matches the character \ literally
n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative: $
$ assert position at end of a line
. matches any character (except newline)
\\ matches the character \ literally
n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
(?=(?:(?!\\n).)*Length) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
(?:(?!\\n).)* Non-capturing group
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?!\\n) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
\\ matches the character \ literally
n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
. matches any character (except newline)
Length matches the characters Length literally (case sensitive)
(?:(?:(?!\\n).)*?(?<Length>[0-9]+\s*(?:-\s*[0-9]+))\s+(?<UnitOfMeasure>\S+)|(?:(?!\\n).)*?Length:\s*(?<Length>(?:(?!\\n).)*))? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
1st Alternative: (?:(?!\\n).)*?(?<Length>[0-9]+\s*(?:-\s*[0-9]+))\s+(?<UnitOfMeasure>\S+)
(?:(?!\\n).)*? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
(?!\\n) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
\\ matches the character \ literally
n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
. matches any character (except newline)
(?<Length>[0-9]+\s*(?:-\s*[0-9]+)?) Named capturing group Length
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?:-\s*[0-9]+)? Non-capturing group
- matches the character - literally
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?<UnitOfMeasure>\S+) Named capturing group UnitOfMeasure
\S+ match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
2nd Alternative: (?:(?!\\n).)*?Length:\s*(?<Length>(?:(?!\\n).)*)
(?:(?!\\n).)*? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
(?!\\n) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
\\ matches the character \ literally
n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
. matches any character (except newline)
Length: matches the characters Length: literally (case sensitive)
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?<Length>(?:(?!\\n).)*) Named capturing group Length
(?:(?!\\n).)* Non-capturing group
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?!\\n) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
\\ matches the character \ literally
n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
. matches any character (except newline)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
J modifier: Allow duplicate subpattern names
```